# Passing Data through Local Maps - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a directive with an isolated scope that accepts a function reference.

**Directive:**

```
return {
    ...
    scope: {
        parentFunctionReference: '&tParentFunctionReference'
    },
    ...
};
```

**Function:**

```
 function functionReference(id) {
     return self.getSomeNameOfId(id);
 }
```

My question is, Why Am I forced to use local maps or invoke functions like this `scope.parentFunctionReference()('id');` in order to get the actual result of the function and not its reference?

I understand that the function evaluates VS the parent scope, but why is it returning a reference?

Comment: can you post your html?